# SQL to get values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

am stuck in a sql problem.  I need something like this

```
M S C

1 sent 12
1 checked 15
1 rejected 9
2 sent 20
2 checked 18
3 rejected 10
```

Where M stands for Month, S for Status and C for Count respectively.  What i want to achieve is to group the above example by Month

Wanted:

M S C

```
1 sent     12
  checked  15
  rejected  9
2 sent     20
  checked  18
  rejected 10
```

**EDIT 1**

Right now the sql statement looks like this:

```
select month, status, sum(hit) as count
from myTable
where dateletter between "date from" and "date to"
group by month,status order by month, status
```

**Edit 2**

How would i achieve this too

```
         1  2

Sent     12 20

Checked  15 18

Rejected 9  10
```

where 1,2 represent the month values from database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Help us help you: 1) What do your tables look like? 2) What does your current query look like?

Comment: @MrE i have put the sql statement as asked

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes no it is there

Comment: @sameer whats wrong with your existing group by statement?  U just want to remove the extra 1s and 2s?

Comment: @tbone yes, just want to group it by month..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT month AS M, status AS S, SUM(hit) AS C
FROM myTable
WHERE dateletter BETWEEN "date from" AND "date to"
GROUP BY month, status
ORDER BY month, status
```

In the query you cannot group further, you will have to do this in a report. The query is OK and can serve as record source for a report. In such a report, you would insert a group header for each month.

---

You could however make a pivot query

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT month AS M, status AS S, SUM(hit) AS C
    FROM myTable
    WHERE dateletter BETWEEN "date from" AND "date to"
    GROUP BY month, status
  )
  PIVOT (
    SUM(C)
    FOR S IN ('sent', 'checked', 'rejected')
  );
```

This would return the status in columns

```
M sent checked rejected
1  12   15       9
2  20   18      10
```

Comment: Yes, however I have not tested my example.

Comment: i have tried but it is not working. it says 

ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 22

Comment: for S in (select distinct(status) from tablename) should be working too?

Comment: I cannot test it on my oracle 9.2. I changed my example slightly to fit your query. I found oracle 11 pivot examples [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506)

Comment: Yes, a sub-select would work, See the syntax [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDCEJJE). Or you could use the keyword ANY. `FOR S IN (ANY)`.

Comment: i tried a simple distinct select sub query, yet it is not working

Comment: for sub query i must use pivot xml.. anyways thanks for the answer, helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly clear what you want from your example, but it sounds like you want to show the details for each month and status, but also want a group total for each month.

You can do this using a rollup analytic function in Oracle:

```
create table tst2
(
m number,
s varchar2(10),
hit number
);


insert into tst2 values (1,'sent',3);
insert into tst2 values (1,'checked',2);
insert into tst2 values (1,'rejected',4);
insert into tst2 values (2,'sent',6);
insert into tst2 values (2,'checked',1);
insert into tst2 values (2,'rejected',3);
commit;

select m,s,sum(hit) as cnt,
case
  when (grouping(s) = 1 and grouping(m) = 1) then 'All total'
  when (grouping(s) = 1 and grouping(m) = 0) then 'Month total'
  else null
end as "Comment"
from tst2
group by rollup(m,s);
```

And you'll get

> ---
>
> ```
>      1 sent                3           
>      1 checked             2           
>      1 rejected            4           
>      1                     9 Month total
>      2 sent                6            
>      2 checked             1           
>      2 rejected            3           
>      2                    10 Month total
>                           19 All total
> ```

See here for Oracle docs RE: [analytic and reporting functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm#i1007434).

Comment: i do not want total for each month.. instead i want only the month to be displayed once per row as shown in my question

Answer (score 1):

Using the `BREAK ON` syntax of SQL*Plus :

```
> BREAK ON M

>           SELECT 1 m , 'sent' s   , 12 c FROM dual
2 UNION ALL SELECT 1   , 'checked'  , 15   FROM dual
3 UNION ALL SELECT 1   , 'rejected' , 9    FROM dual
4 UNION ALL SELECT 2   , 'sent'     , 20   FROM dual
5 UNION ALL SELECT 2   , 'checked'  , 18   FROM dual
6 UNION ALL SELECT 3   , 'rejected' , 10   FROM dual

         M S                 C
---------- -------- ----------
         1 sent             12
           checked          15
           rejected          9
         2 sent             20
           checked          18
         3 rejected         10
```

So, with your example:

```
SET LINESIZE 2000 TRIMSPOOL ON TRIM ON
BREAK ON MONTH
SPOOL file.txt

SELECT month, status, SUM(hit) AS count
  FROM myTable
 WHERE dateletter BETWEEN "date from" AND "date to"
 GROUP BY month, status
 ORDER BY month, status;

SPOOL OFF
```

Comment: what if i do not want the 'sent', 'checked' hardcoded but values from the db?

Comment: what if i want all the values from the database.. that is month from db, status from db and alse sum from db